# How to add provider specific entries using dnscontrol?

Tags: dns

I am trying to configure my domain's dns records using [dnscontrol](https://github.com/StackExchange/dnscontrol)

There is a DKIM TXT record that is over 255 characters. Route53 and Google Cloud DNS requires the record to be split into multiple strings, but CloudFlare does not support multiple strings for TXT records.

I tried adding a separate `D('mydomain.com', REG_NONE ...);`, for cloudflare, but it is failing with error

> Executing javascript in dnsconfig.js: mydomain.com is declared more than once

How can conditionally add records depending on the provider with dnscontrol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If different providers have different DNS records things are going to get very confusing very fast. We don't recommend it.

Usually the only thing dnscontrol will do that is similar is a meta type like `ALIAS()` which does different things for different providers.  That won't help in this situation.

My recommendation is to not use CloudFlare until they support multiple strings in a TXT record.  Have you filed a feature request with them?

Comment: Thank you. I will file a feature request.